# Optional one-to-one relation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

When I have 2 models like this:

```
public class PredictionGroup
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PredictionGroupId { get; set; }

    public Guid? ResultPredictionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResultPredictionId")]
    public Prediction ResultPrediction { get; set; }

    public List<Prediction> Predictions { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PredictionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid PredictionGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PredictionGroupId")]
    public PredictionGroup PredictionGroup { get; set; }
}
```

This will be generated:

```
CreateTable(
    "Website.PredictionGroups",
    c => new
        {
            PredictionGroupId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
            ResultPredictionId = c.Guid(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.PredictionGroupId)
    .ForeignKey("Website.Predictions", t => t.ResultPredictionId)
    .Index(t => t.ResultPredictionId);

CreateTable(
    "Website.Predictions",
    c => new
        {
            PredictionId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
            PredictionGroupId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            PredictionGroup_PredictionGroupId = c.Guid(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.PredictionId)
    .ForeignKey("Website.PredictionGroups", t => t.PredictionGroupId)
    .ForeignKey("Website.PredictionGroups", t => t.PredictionGroup_PredictionGroupId)
    .Index(t => t.PredictionGroupId)
    .Index(t => t.PredictionGroup_PredictionGroupId);
```

When I try to enter this in my database I get the error: `Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Site.Data.Prediction_PredictionGroup' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.`

Can somebody shine a light on this?

Comment: Is your last edit the answer? Maybe you can convert it to an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this Fluent API code:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PredictionGroup>()
            .HasOptional(m => m.ResultPrediction)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("PredictionResultGroupId"));
```

The `MapKey` is optional, but I was hoping it could been done with just annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you models are correct and that is why you needed to add Fluent API code.  You shouldn't need the Fluent API code for this.  The [ForeignKey] definitions goes on the property that is the foreign key value and points to the object it is the key for.  So the property attribute goes on ResultPredictionId and says it for the property ResultPrediction.  Currently it's done the opposite.

```
public class PredictionGroup
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PredictionGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResultPrediction")] //this is the key, point it to the object
    public Guid? ResultPredictionId { get; set; }


    public Prediction ResultPrediction { get; set; }

    public List<Prediction> Predictions { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PredictionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("PredictionGroup")]
    public Guid PredictionGroupId { get; set; }


    public PredictionGroup PredictionGroup { get; set; }
}
```